# Correct way to inherit from Abstract class with dependent interfaces in C#

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, oop, design-patterns

I have an abstract class for sending and retrieving messages.

```
public abstract class MailClient
{
    public IAuthentication MailAuthentication { get; set; }

    internal MailClient(IAuthentication mailAuthenticaton)
    {
        this.MailAuthentication = mailAuthenticaton;
    }

    public abstract State SendMessage(IMessage message);
    public abstract List<IMessage> GetEmails();
}
```

I want to create a concrete class (let say for yahoo email messages). So, I create yahoo client that inherits from the abstract Mail client, and uses YahooMessage object that contains details for the message that needs to be sent or received.

```
public class YahooClient : MailClient
{
    private YahooConfiguration configuration = new YahooConfiguration();

    public YahooClient (string username, string password) : base(new YahooAuthentication(username, password)) 
    { 
    }

    public override List<YahooMessage> GetMessages()
    {
        //Code for retrieving emails
    }

    public override State SendMessage(YahooMessage message)
    {
        //Code for sending emails
    }
}
```

YahooMessage implements the IMessage interface, and adds few new properties that are specific for Yahoo.

However, I got error because "SendMessage" and "GetMessages" are not implemented with the correct signature in the Child class (YahooClient). Instead of IMessage I use YahooMessage, that implements the IMessage interface.

This is obviously the wrong approach. What would be the suitable approach to achieve the desired functionality?

Comment: How is a YahooMessage different from any other kind of email message?  I'm wondering if you're creating a distinction that doesn't need to be.  Second, the base class is setting up a *contract* that child classes are expected to conform to.  You're trying to change the contract in your subclass.

Comment: Where are you defining YahooMessage?

Comment: You both are right, YahooMessage is unnecessary distinction.

Comment: I would think that if your abstract class doesn't partially provide some code/logic, it would be easier to only use Interfaces.

Comment: I am setting my MailAuthentication in my Abstract class. Of course, you can propose better solution, I am open for suggestions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would change your base class definition to also be generic.

```
public abstract class MailClient<TMessage> where TMessage: IMessage
{
    public IAuthentication MailAuthentication { get; set; }

    internal MailClient(IAuthentication mailAuthenticaton)
    {
        this.MailAuthentication = mailAuthenticaton;
    }

    public abstract State SendMessage(TMessage message);
    public abstract List<TMessage> GetEmails();
}
```

This then gives you the implementation of

```
public class YahooClient : MailClient<YahooMessage>
{
    private YahooConfiguration configuration = new YahooConfiguration();

    public YahooClient (string username, string password) 
        : base(new YahooAuthentication(username, password)) 
    { 
    }

    public override List<YahooMessage> GetMessages()
    {
        //Code for retrieving emails
    }

    public override State SendMessage(YahooMessage message)
    {
        //Code for sending emails
    }
}
```

Comment: This implies that YahooMessage is derived from IMessage, which might not be the case.

Comment: OP states that it implements IMessage.

Comment: Totally overlooked that, my bad!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However, I am not sure if this scenario will be posible:

MailClient<HotmailMessage> client = new YahooClient(username, pass);

Which will be a problem.

Comment: It will not be as `YahooClient` is typed to take a `YahooMessage` not a `HotmailMessage`. However, `MailClient<IMessage> client = new YahooClient(username, pass)` would work.